# Where is my model ship?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Mass Effect 3 the Sovereign model ship isn't appearing. I know where it should be - the engineering subdeck - but it's not showing up. There's no option to pick it up. What sort of glitch is this? Is there any way to fix it?